# Programming, SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I get the error:

> ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias:

I cant figure out whats wrong with it.

```
SELECT p.id as id_produk, p.nama_produk, p.stok, p.url_title, p.deskripsi, p.file_name, p.id_kategori_produk, p.fk_jenis_id,p.fk_merk_id, p.fk_gudang_id, p.created_at, kp.id, kp.nama_kategori, jm.id, jm.jenis_material, mm.id, mm.merk_material, gm.id, gm.gudang_material 
FROM produk as p, kategori_produk as kp, 
produk as p, 
jenis_material as jm, 
produk as p, 
merk_material as mm, 
produk as p, 
gudang_material as gm 
WHERE p.id_kategori_produk = kp.id, 
p.fk_jenis_id = jm.id, 
p.fk_merk_id = mm.id, 
p.fk_gudang_id = gm.id 
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\telkomakses\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: That doesn't strike me as a very good duplicate as the accepted answer doesn't offer any kind of explanation and is specifically about JOINs.

Comment: how to solve it sir??

Answer (score 1):

In your code more than one table using the same alias. Or using same alais at diffrent parts.

eg. here alias p is using two times.(in your code its a lot of times)

```
   produk as p, kategori_produk as kp, produk as p,
```

So try to use different alias like

```
   produk as p1, kategori_produk as kp, produk as p2,
```

And next error is at **where** part. You cannot use comma to seperate expresstions. you have to give AND or Or operators. change that line

```
 WHERE p.id_kategori_produk = kp.id, p.fk_jenis_id = jm.id, p.fk_merk_id = mm.id, p.fk_gudang_id = gm.id
```

to the following

```
 WHERE p.id_kategori_produk = kp.id AND p.fk_jenis_id = jm.id AND p.fk_merk_id = mm.id AND p.fk_gudang_id = gm.id
```

Comment: when i try it
i get this error sir

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' p.fk_jenis_id = jm.id, p.fk_merk_id = mm.id, p.fk_gudang_id = gm.id ORDER BY' at line 4

Comment: can you give that full query

Comment: full query at the bottom sir

Comment: error is at "where" part. You cannot use comma to seperate expresstions. you have to give AND or Or operators. change the fourth line to the following >>> WHERE p.id_kategori_produk = kp.id AND p.fk_jenis_id = jm.id AND p.fk_merk_id = mm.id AND p.fk_gudang_id = gm.id